# Troubleshooting : Google Calendar Insert API error "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes"

Tags: google-api, google-api-client

For testing our application I need to insert/update google calendar events and verify edge cases like if a meeting invite is > 30 days it should not be shown to end user. I am doing this setup for a single gmail id testaccount@.com and trying to manipulate events to cover all the edge cases.

Following this link - https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

1) I created a new project https://console.cloud.google.com.

2) Enabled Google Calendar API

3) Set up OAuth Client for credentials.json

4) Ran python quick start to get 10 calendar event - to verify step 3 was correct.

5) Now to insert an event added following scope on consent screen
   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events

6) Regenerate credential, so that it does have newly added scope for inserting event.

I am getting following error message - 
HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."

I have also tried using email id in place of "primay" and again ending up with the same error.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem (=error message).
Check out in the top of the demo software the following lines:

```
# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']
```

and modify to

```
# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
```

then delete your token.pickle file,
then rerun your script.

Comment: For windows environment delete the file token.json

Comment: but what about if you only need calendar.readonly to view events & don't want scare user by giving you permission to write/delete when won't need it? How can you make .readonly work without running to that error?

Comment: It seems that at some point the devs maintaining this API decided to switch the file format storing the token from pickle to json, but forgot to update the dóc

Answer (score 1):

If your all credentials is done perfectly. you can just simplly edit a line
Go to your index.php or your filename where you generated get client and overrice the line below

```
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
```

To

```
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
```

and also make sure you have permission to create events.

Hope it will helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
```

Change this to:

```
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_EVENTS);
```